# Amazon S3 issues getting SSL to work with c# sdk

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm using the Amazon AWS .NET SDK v1.2.1.

The following code throws an exception after failing a DNS lookup for `myBucket.more.https` which is clearly not what it should be looking for...

```
AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config()
{
    ServiceURL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com",
    CommunicationProtocol = Amazon.S3.Model.Protocol.HTTPS,
};

using (AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey,secretKey, S3Config))
{
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(inputBytes))
    {
        request.WithBucketName("myBucket.more")
                .WithKey(output.Name)
                .WithInputStream(ms);

        using (S3Response response = client.PutObject(request))
        {
                        Log.Message("File Sent: " + output.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `https://` from the front of the ServiceURL it throws a web exception with:

`"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."`

So how am I suppose to get SSL working?

The only way I've managed so far is with the following, which is not secure:

```
AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config()
{
    ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
    CommunicationProtocol = Amazon.S3.Model.Protocol.HTTP,
};
```

**UPDATE**

If I don't pass a custom S3Config to `CreateAmazonS3Client`, it is still failing with:

`"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."`

`"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ServiceUrl should be `S3.amazonaws.com` without the `https://` in front. That is the default setting as is `HTTPS` for the `Communication` protocol. That's why you get the same error when you don't set the settings manually.

## Update

**EU buckets cannot contain periods(.) in the name if you want to use HTTPS.**

Comment: The bucket was created hours ago, and works perfectly if I turn SSL off. With the default config I get:   "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

Comment: although I guess that could still be down to DNS at it has to match the certificate!

Comment: @Jim - have you tried looking at the requests going across the wire with a tool like fiddler?

Comment: @Jim - another thing - I don't think EU buckets over SSL work if they have periods(.) or Capitals in the name. You don't have one of those do you?

Comment: The actual bucket name I'm using has a period '.' in it, which messes up the SSL certificates!

Comment: @Jim - updated my answer to reflect the solution from my earlier comment :)

Comment: If you want to use SSL with a period in the bucket name you must use the "version 1" URL style. e.g. https://s3.amazonaws.com/my.bucket.with.periods/path/to/file.txt

Comment: @Uriah - Except that doesn't work with EU buckets. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @geoff - To use path style buckets you must use the [region specific endpoint](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3912). The S3 EU region has an unpublished endpoint of `s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`. I have uploaded an example image: [DNS style](http://eutest.uriah.com.s3.amazonaws.com/flowers.jpg), [SSL with path style](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eutest.uriah.com/flowers.jpg)